# jQuery animations mess up in IE8 and earlier

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Here is my site: 
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/jquery/basicDemo12-bugfix-3.htm

It works fine on firefox, chrome, safari and ie9, but messes up in IE8 and 7.

When you click on an image it expands. When you click on another image, any expanded images contract. I think its this second part of the jQuery causing problems. With IE8 and 7 the animation end up in the correct place, but all the images jump around before then.

Here is the code:

```
    $(".image-div").click(function () {


        var divRefTwo = $(".image-div").not(this);
        $(".image-div").not(this).animate({
                width: '250px',
                left: '0px',
                marginRight: '0px',
                backgroundPosition: '-125px'
            }, 400, function() {
                $(divRefTwo).css('z-index','1');
            });

        if ($(this).css('z-index') == 1) {
            $(this).css('z-index','2');
            $(this).animate({
                width: '500px',
                left: '-125px',
                marginRight: '-250px',
                backgroundPosition: '0px'
            }, 500, function() {
                //
            });
        }
        else {
            var divRef = this;
            $(this).animate({
                width: '250px',
                left: '0px',
                marginRight: '0px',
                backgroundPosition: '-125px'
            }, 500, function() {
                $(divRef).css('z-index','1');
            });
        }

    });
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Its quite hard to debug as the issue only presents itself while the animation is running.

Thanks

UPDATE- Ive tried adding conditional statements to only run the animation (that shrinks expanded elements) when necessary, but with this it doesn't run at all:

```
        if ($(".image-div").not(this).css('width') == '500px') {

        $(".image-div").not(this).animate({
                width: '250px',
                left: '0px',
                marginRight: '0px',
                backgroundPosition: '-125px'
            }, 400, function() {
                $(divRefTwo).css('z-index','1');
            });

        }

        else {
        }
```

UPDATE2 - Ive updated the latest demo here: 
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/jquery2/basicDemo12-bugfix-6.htm

The conditional statements prevent the animation from running on divs that aren't supposed to expand anyway. So this has fixed the problem of all the divs jumping about.

However when the animation runs on the clicked on div (like its supposed to), that div still expands weirdly on IE7 and 8. It seems like this is to do with the background-position animating weirdly.

Comment: adding the css for the elements in context of the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: I can add it if you like but its all in the document head. Let me know if you'd like me to add it aswell. Thanks

Comment: just for your information. If the screen width (I got 1960px) is bigger that ~1624px (if all the images are partly visible) your animation never start! I suggest you to start from the beginning with that code. (It's not provided here and it's buggy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a sneaky suspicion that IE is not updating the CSS values after the animation.  This means that when you click on an image the other images are animated *again*.  I checked with this:

```
$($(".image-div")[0]).css('background-position')
```

In IE it is undefined.  In FF it has the correct value.  So the animation is taking place in IE since the value is not there.  Why this is I wouldn't know.

It may be an idea to store the state of each image somehow (maybe `.data`) and then use *that* to determine whther to restore the image (using your animation).

Try this:

```
$(".image-div").click(function () {
    // reset expanded images
    $(".image-div").not(this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('z-index') == '2') {
            $(this).animate({
                width: '250px',
                left: '0px',
                marginRight: '0px',
                backgroundPosition: '-125px'
            }, 400, function() { $(this).css('z-index','1'); });
        }
    });

    // toggle clicked image
    if ($(this).css('z-index') == 1) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '500px',
            left: '-125px',
            marginRight: '-250px',
            backgroundPosition: '0px'
        }, 500, function() { $(this).css('z-index','2'); });
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '250px',
            left: '0px',
            marginRight: '0px',
            backgroundPosition: '-125px'
        }, 500, function() { $(this).css('z-index','1'); });
    }

});
```

Comment: Ok that looks like quite a major rewrite.... Could there be a similar solution like an if statement that checks for the value and only runs the animation if it needs to? Thanks

Comment: yes --- that's what I mean.  Instead of *always* running the animation using the values provided by the browser, rather only run when the image needs to be restored.  It seems as though you are using the z-index as a flag anyway, so you could pop in a simple `if` to check whether the animation should run.

Comment: Ive updated my answer. I tried adding conditional statements but now that particular animation doesn't run at all.

Comment: I just tested it by running the code in the console --- it seems to work.  I'll change my answer to include the enstire script you could try.

Comment: What do you mean by 'works'? The code works fine in FF (as the original code did), but also has the same issue as the original ie IE8. Thanks

Comment: Working, well sort of. I haven't tested with IE7 yet but IE8 no longer has the issue, but now the z-index changes at the wrong time. I wont be able to look at this properly until tonight but assuming I can get it working ill post the working code here and mark your answer as correct. thanks

Comment: Ive updated my question and added the latest demo here: smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/jquery2/basicDemo12-bugfix-6.htm

Answer (score 8):

### Two things caused this problem

- IE prior to version 9 does not
  support background-position, it
  supports background-position-x and
  background-position-y
- jQuery will not
  switch to supported styles when it
  should

### Forcing jQuery to use supported styles

```
var default_css = $.css;
$.css = function (elem, name, extra) {
    name = $.camelCase(name);

    // if requested css name is not backgroundPosition then jQuery can handel it
    if (!name.match(/.*backgroundPosition/i) || !elem.currentStyle || elem.currentStyle[name]) return default_css.apply(this, arguments);

    // if backgroundPosition is supported by browser then return backgroundPosition value
    var style = elem.style;
    if (!extra && style && style[name]) return style[name];

    // if we get here browser doesn't support backgroundPosition, we need to fix it
    return default_css(elem, 'backgroundPositionX', extra) + ' ' + default_css(elem, 'backgroundPositionY', extra);
};
```

Put this script in page right after jQuery-1.6.1 script.

> ***Tested with** IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari*

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Yes, it seems to be because the collapse animation is running on all of the other images, it would be far more efficient and should solve your problem if you run the collapse animation on the expanded image only.

I could demonstrate this in a jsfiddle if needed

---

Your update to your question definitely has the right idea, you only want to run the animation on the expanded image.

You could add a class every time you expand a image    `.addClass('expanded')`  and then check for that class. Obviously removing that class once its collapsed again.

Your **update does not work** because it needs to run through a `.each()` function

```
$(this).siblings().each(function(){

 if ($(this).width() == '500px') {

        $(this).animate({
                width: '250px',
                left: '0px',
                marginRight: '0px',
                backgroundPosition: '-125px'
            }, 400, function() {
                $(divRefTwo).css('z-index','1');
            });

        }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Blowsie. Ive got the non clicked on divs to stop jumping around, but the div you have clicked on still animates weirdly in IE7 and 8. Thanks

Comment: Since youve updated your code to make it similar to this, your online example works fine for me in both IE7 and IE8

Answer (score 1):

I've checked out the link you gave. Be sure to validate your html page. Better browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari and all that lot, will understand your html event with a few errors. IE is not as flexible. An html page that is not W3C valid will hold a few suprises.

And the link you gave, **is not W3C valid.**

Comment: Ive validated the latest demo page (see updated question). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
        $(".image-div").not(this).each(function(){
            if ($(this).css('z-index') != 1)
            {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: '250px',
                    left: '0px',
                    marginRight: '0px',
                    backgroundPosition: '-125px'
                }, 400, function() {
                    $(divRefTwo).css('z-index','1');
                });
            }
        });
```